# reticulate calling Python in R gives me "null" results

Tags: python, r, null, r-markdown, reticulate

I'm using **R markdown** and trying to access to variables in the python chunk from r chunk, but the results return `NULL` in the r chunk. I tried to follow the instruction [here](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/r_markdown.html). My code as follow, what is the issue here?

````
```{r setup}
library(reticulate)
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python")
```

```{python}
import pandas as pd
Dict = {'x1': [1,2,3], 'x2': [4,5,6], 'x3': [7,8,9] }
my_df2 = pd.DataFrame(Dict)
print(my_df2) # works fine
``` 

```{r}
print(py$my_df2) # return NULL
```
````

Thanks!

Comment: Your code (in the form I edited it) produces an error for me since `pd` is unknown. When I add `import pandas as pd` (and remove `use_python(...)` since I have no `/usr/local/bin/python`), the code works without problems in RStudio.

Comment: @RalfStubner thx for replying. I also tried to remove use_python(), also specified import pandas as pd, still NULL in my R chunk. Something wrong with my Rstudio?

Comment: Are you able to access simpler variables from R, say a double?